# Directly upgrade the Magento 2.1.5 to 2.3

Tags: magento2, php, magento-upgrade, versioning

Can we directly upgrade the Magento 2.1.5 to 2.3? Magento 2.1 supports the PHP version 5.6, 7 & 7.1 only and Magento 2.3 supports 7.1.3,7.2,7.3. Both support the different versions while readiness checks it always raised an error “**requires PHP ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.6) does not satisfy that requirement**”.

Anyone, can you please let me know the process of how to upgrade Magento 2.1 to 2.3. I am running this on my local window machine.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to upgrade PHP to **PHP version 7.1.3** then upgrade your Magento version following the document guide of Magento:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

If you can't do it by yourself, you can hire a Magento migration expert who helps you to complete your project even in the local.